# finding x[0] from the region of convergence

Tags: z-transform, poles-zeros

I have the ROC of a signal $x[n]$ with $z$-transform $X(z)$ as below:
[image]

Now I am wondering how I can find $x[0]$ by not calculating inverse z transform based on the roc, I am looking for a simpler, and faster way.

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer:
initial value theorem, which states that $$\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} X(z) = x[0]$$

Comment: Nice! Now all you have to do is find the expression for X(z). If you have trouble with that, happy to help ;)